# Проверить значение кастомного поля вне цикла

Tags: php, wordpress

В проекте использую ACF, создала кастомное поле [true/false](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/true-false/).

Необходимо вывести посты с полем `active` в один блок, а остальные в другой.

Код имеет такую структуру:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'client',
    'post_status'=>'publish',
    'posts_per_page'=>-1,
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>


<?php if ( get_field( 'is_active') ) : ?>

    <div class="bg-gray">
        <div class="container">
            <h2 class="page-head_sub-title">aktive </h2>

<?php else: ?>

    <div class="bg-white no-active">
        <div class="container">
            <h2 class="page-head_sub-title">not active</h2>
<?php endif; ?>



        <div class="row equal customers-wrap">

            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
                <?php $e = 0; ?>

                <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

                    <?php
                    $is_active = get_field('is_active');
                    //var_dump($is_active);
                    ?>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-3 d-flex pb-3 ">
                        <a href="#galleryClients" class="card card-block" data-slide-to="<?php echo $e; ?>">
                            <?php
                                $thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
                                $thumbnail_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumbnail_id, 'thumbnail-size', true );
                            ?>
                            <div class="item" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#clientModal">
                                <div class="customers-wrap_item ">
                                    <img class="img-fluid" src="<?php echo $thumbnail_url[0]; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <?php $e++; ?>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Но этот код не работает как ожидается. Скорее всего потому что проверка поля происходит вне цикла. Если провести проверку внутри цикла, то код сработает, но это изменит структуру `html`.

Как можно вызвать проверку на наличие значения в поле вне цикла вывода постов?

**UPD**

Указала `id` страницы, на которой выводятся посты:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'client',
    'post_status'=>'publish',
    'posts_per_page'=>-1,
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

 ?>


<?php if ( get_field( 'is_active', 289) ) : ?>

<?php
$is_active = get_field('is_active', 289);
var_dump($is_active);
?>

    <div class="bg-gray">
        <div class="container">
            <h2 class="page-head_sub-title">active </h2>

<?php else: ?>

    <div class="bg-white no-active">
        <div class="container">
            <h2 class="page-head_sub-title">not active</h2>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Но `var_dump($is_active);` не выводит никакого значения, т.к. находится вне цикла.

Ожидаемая структура `html` такая:

Если в посте поставлена галочка active

```
    <div class="bg-gray">
        <div class="container">
            <h2 class="page-head_sub-title">active </h2>
            <?php the_post ?> 
        </div>
    </div>
```

Если в посте не поставлена галочка active

```
<div class="bg-white no-active">
        <div class="container">
            <h2 class="page-head_sub-title">not active </h2>
            <?php the_post ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**UPD 1.0**

С помощью этого кода удалось вывести посты со статусом **not active**:

```
<?php
$args = array (
    'post_type' => 'client',
    'post_status'=>'publish',
    'posts_per_page'=>-1,
    'meta_query' => array (
        array (
            'value' => '0'

        )
    )


);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для вывода **active** использую код:

```
<?php
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'client',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'is_active',
        'compare' => '==',
        'value' => '1'
    )
)
);
$the_query = new WP_Query($args);
?>
```

Для вывода **not active** использую код:

```
<?php
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'client',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'is_active',
        'compare' => '==',
        'value' => '0'
    )
)
);
$the_query = new WP_Query($args);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Функция get_field() имеет второй параметр - $post_id. По умолчанию это текущий пост в цикле. Вне цикла номер поста не определен, и get_field() возвращает неизвестно что (скорее всего, пустое значение). Вне цикла нужно указать $post_id таким образом:

```
get_field( 'is_active', $post_id) ;
```

и вы получите значение требуемого поля у нужного поста.

Чтобы сохранить структуру html и получать значения поля is_active у постов в цикле, надо вынести `if ( have_posts() )` и `while` выше проверки поля is_active:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'client',
    'post_status'=>'publish',
    'posts_per_page'=>-1,
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>


<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php $e = 0; ?>
    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

        <?php
        $is_active = get_field('is_active');
        ?>


        <?php if ( $is_active ) : ?>

            <div class="bg-gray">
                <div class="container">
                    <h2 class="page-head_sub-title">aktive </h2>

        <?php else: ?>

            <div class="bg-white no-active">
                <div class="container">
                    <h2 class="page-head_sub-title">not active</h2>

        <?php endif; ?>

                    <div class="row equal customers-wrap">

                        <div class="col-md-3 col-md-3 d-flex pb-3 ">
                            <a href="#galleryClients" class="card card-block" data-slide-to="<?php echo $e; ?>">
                                <?php
                                    $thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
                                    $thumbnail_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumbnail_id, 'thumbnail-size', true );
                                ?>
                                <div class="item" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#clientModal">
                                    <div class="customers-wrap_item ">
                                        <img class="img-fluid" src="<?php echo $thumbnail_url[0]; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>

                    <?php $e++; ?>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: не помогло, выводит `NULL`

Comment: а $post_id вы какой указали? Надо же указывать id той записи, что нужна

Comment: а есть способ без указания конкретного `id` ? постов может быть очень много (уже больше 30).

Comment: кроме того, `var_dump` ничего не выводит вне цикла, даже с указанием конкретного `id`

Comment: var_dump - чего? И не работать он не может. Даже если значение пустое, так и выведет - string(0) ""  В общем, покажите, какая вам нужна структура html

Comment: обновила вопрос

Comment: спасибо большое за помощь. код работает, но ломает весь `html`. наверное не правильно объяснила. нужно чтобы все посты с `active` выводились в блоке `bg-gray`, а все остальные посты в блоке `bg-white`. сейчас каждый пост выводится отдельно и занимает всю ширину экрана, а не `col-md-3`. и у div container нет закрывающего тега

Comment: покажите полную верстку в первом и во втором случае, со всеми зарывающими дивами, а то у вас в этом куске кода закрывающих не хватает

Comment: вот полный код https://jsfiddle.net/auedo934/1/ (не обращайте внимание на код  модального окна)

Comment: да нет, дайте чистый html, как должен быть выведен пост. Без всякого php внутри. Я не могу понять, чего вы хотите добиться.

Comment: вот https://jsfiddle.net/auedo934/3/

Comment: и вот этот some content - это и есть контент поста? И таких постов может быть 30? и у КАЖДОГО есть поле is_active?

Comment: да, именно так выводится. при создании у каждого поста есть чекбокс с галочкой `is active`

Comment: ну и как это вы хотите поставить общую обертку active или не active? У вас внутри 30 постов, одни могут быть active, другие - нет. И как принимать решение, во что их всех оборачивать? Тут с логикой проблема.